# Highmaps hover effect/mouseout color change

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

I want to disable the hover effect entirely 
this is code a snippet

```
 series : [{
            data : data,
            mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
            joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code'],
            name: 'Population density',
            states: {
                hover: {
                    enabled:false
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '/km²'
            }
        }]
```

but still when I mouse out there is some color effect is there 
here is a jsfiddle [highmaps fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/plotoptions/series-states-hover/)(please change the series options  as above )

how to fix that color effect when mouse out happens from the map point, any help or reference will be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately at this moment this is related with known bug: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2802

Comment: @SebastianBochan: With some trick you can do it as below as I have answered and its working fine

Comment: @SebastianBochan how can we have a double click event in highmaps because custom event is only working with the highcharts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some struggle I got the solution of the above problem you just have to take the all the points object of the series data and on hover give them the same color as they are having currently, but you can not give the color directly like this

```
 states: {
            hover: {
                color:this.color
            }
        },
```

Hence you can put some hack like this

```
  $('#container').highcharts('Map', options);
           var points = $('#container').highcharts().series[0].data;

           for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {


               points[i].pointAttr.hover.fill = points[i].color;

           }
```

and problem is solved...!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution without jquery:

```
const map = new Highcharts.Map(chartOptions);

(function() {
    var points = map.series[0].data;
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        points[i].pointAttr.hover.fill = points[i].color;
    }
})();
```

Just pop this in after you instantiate your map.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions of @Vikas did not work for me. pointAttr was not 'defined'.

Setting the hover color:null and brightness:0 worked for me:

```
states: {
    hover: {
        color: null,  // Set no specific color to use original color
        brightness: 0 // Prevent brightness effect
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could disable it, like this:

```
states: {
        hover: {
            enabled: false,
        }
    },
```